# Does dU Always Mean Exchanging Heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

What do you think about this view:

The two principles of classical thermodynamics, the first and the second, never pertain to the internal energy $E$ of the system but the quantity $dU$ they use is only the heat which the system (closed) exchanges with the outside world. The fact that $dU$ is only exchanging heat is seen most clearly for an isochoric system (having volume $v = const$) for which the combined I and II principle reads $$dU = TdS.  \tag 1$$Indeed, integrating both sides of eq.(1) yields:$$\int_0^U dU = T \int_0^S dS,  \tag 2$$giving$$\frac{U}{T} = S, \tag 3$$which means that when entropy $S$ is zero the quantity $U$ will also be zero. However, that quantity $U$ cannot be the internal energy because it only shows up when there is non-zero entropy $S$.

Case in point. A simple harmonic oscillator with absolutely constant amplitude and phase does possess internal energy $E$ despite the fact that its entropy $S$ is zero. The entropy $S$ of that oscillator becomes non-zero only when a disorder in oscillator's amplitude and phase kicks in. That disorder, causing the non-zero $dS$ is exactly the reason for that additional (additional to $E$) quantity $dU$ to appear.

Therefore, even in statistical mechanics, when a connection is sought between $S$ and $U$, such as$$S = k log R = k \left\{    \left( 1 + \frac {U} {\varepsilon}         \right) log\left(  1 + \frac {U} {\varepsilon}        \right) -    \frac {U} {\varepsilon} log\frac {U} {\varepsilon}                            \right\},$$where k is the Boltzmann constant, $R$ is the number of the possible Boltzmann ``complexes'' and $\varepsilon$ is Planck's elementary energy element (quantum of energy), the meaning of $U$ must only be exchanging heat and is never to be confused with the internal energy $E$ of the oscillator. Thanks.

NOTE: The essence of the above view is that $dU$ is always the exchanging part of the internal energy and should never be confused with the internal energy $\textit{per se}$ of the system. Despite the fact that from the point of view of classical thermodynamics, $\underline{ultimately, \ the \ exchanging \ energy \ is \ exchanging \ heat}$, to avoid confusion, the above view discusses specifically isochoric system. Isochoric system is also of special importance because this is how the linear harmonic oscillator is $\underline{always}$ treated, $with \ U \ being \ its \ internal \ (vibrational) \ energy \ for \ which \ \frac{dS}{dU} = \frac{1}{T}$ applies. Therefore, it would not be a bad idea in this conversation, for brevity, to stick to isochoric system, although the view at hand applies to other systems as well. Also, although it's trivial, it should be added that temperature $T$ is the temperature of an infinite heat reservoir and therefore it doesn't change when heat $Q$ is added to it or extracted from it. $\underline{Thus, S \ cannot \ be \ a \ function \ of \ the \ T \ of \ a \ given \ heat \ reservoir}$.

Comment: It is clear that if the process is adiabatic then the change in U is not related to heat transfer.

Comment: In the integration (2) why did you suppose that $T$ is not a function of $S$? In general it can be, so the integral is not so easy and all that follows can be very different

Comment: There's a law which states, $\mathrm{d}Q=\mathrm{d}U+\mathrm{d}W$. The signs might be different depending on different conventions. But, in an adiabatic process, the $\mathrm{d}Q=0$, hence $\mathrm{d}U=-\mathrm{d}W$. Obviously, $\mathrm{d}U$ in that case is not the exchange of heat.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

No, $dU$ is not always the exchanged heat.

### Long answer

The first principle of thermodynamics introduces the concept of internal energy $U$ and heat. This internal energy, loosely speaking is the portion of energy not described by external potential energies or mechanic energy. It also says that any change un $U$ is accounted for by heat exchange and work

$\Delta U=Q-W$

In the isochoric case, the volume work vanishes and the changes in $U$ are only due to heat. However, in adiabatic exchanges $U$ changes are only caused by work. Your reasoning is wrong because of an assumption you made unawarely.

In 2, you assume that $T$ is independent of entropy $S$. This leads to the linear relation between $U$ and $S$, which usually does not apply.

In the case of a simple harmonic oscillator, it is critical to point out whether the harmonic potential is in fact due to an external force, in which case it could not be considered as 'internal' energy. This discussion is very subtle because the harmonic potential of coupled oscilators can be considered as part of the internal energy.